# Post Amplify Authentication using ReactJS getting - Login option is not available. Please try another one

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I am able to authenticate through Okta integrated with Amplify, however post login I get the below Error ( as shown on the screenshot )

"Login option is not available. Please try another one"

[image: Error]

Here is my `App.js` and `Login.js`

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Login from "./login"

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
// import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Login/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Auth.configure(awsExports);

class Login extends React.Component {
    async handleCustomFederatedSignIn() {
      try {
        const user = await Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Okta'})
        console.log(user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleCustomFederatedSignIn}>Sign in with Okta</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default Login;
```

Can someone please help me with what am I missing here ?